# store function result in a variable

Tags: php

here is my code

```
function result (){
    $args = array(
         'child_of' => 22,
         'hide_empty' => 0
     );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
      foreach($categories as $category) { 
        echo '<p><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
         } 
}
```

now i need to store the result in a variable.is it possible in php??

Comment: What do you mean by result? What is being displayed?

Comment: Sounds like homework?

Comment: Your function is `returning` nothing

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does now show a basic understanding of the topic

Comment: Have a look at the return keyword: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Answer (score 1):

```
    function result (){
        $args = array(
            'child_of' => 22,
            'hide_empty' => 0
        );
        $result='';
        $categories = get_categories($args);
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            $result.= '<p><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: don't forget the $myResult = result();

Answer (score 0):

For any function, foo, a value is returned by using the return statement

```
function foo(){
    return "bar";
}

$foo = foo();
echo $foo;//displays bar
```